# Insert values into Database with Java

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, ibm-midrange

Hello I have a Jtable and a JFormattedTextField where I input the values to insert into the database.
I used PreparedStatement but the output gives an error [SQL0418] Utilização de marcador de parâmetro ou NULL não válida.

```java
try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://" + host, user, pwd);
            // create new statement from connection
            //Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs; 
            // int rows=table.getRowCount();

             //for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
            // {   
                String PTCDCT = (String)table.getValueAt(0, 0);
                String OFNUPK = (String) table.getValueAt(0, 1);
                String TFCCMP = (String)table.getValueAt(0, 2);
                String TFCPAI = (String)table.getValueAt(0, 3);
                String TPTEMP = (String)table.getValueAt(0, 4);
                int OFNUP = Integer.parseInt(OFNUPK);
                double TPTEM = Double.parseDouble(TPTEMP);
                
       
            String querq = " INSERT INTO SICGA00F55.FTEMPO(TPRNPT, TPNUOF, TPLV01, TPTEMP, TPPZIV, TPRNOP)"
             + "SELECT t.PTRNPP, f.OFNUPK, concat(p.PTSEC, '00000', a.TFNRLC), ?, convert(datetime, ?, 111), MAX(p.TPRNOP) + 1 "
             + "FROM SICGA00F55.TPOSTO t, SICGA00F55.TPOSTCM p, SICGA00F55.FORFAB f, $$CLI00F55.FOFFAN a, SICGA00F55.FTEMPO p"
             + "WHERE t.PTCDCT= ? AND t.PTCDCT= p.PTCDCT AND f.OFNUPK= ? AND "
             + "f.OFNUPK= a.TFSNOF AND a.TFCCMP= ? AND a.TFCPAI= ?";
                
          
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(querq);
                preparedStmt.setDouble(1, TPTEM);
                preparedStmt.setString(2, textId.getText());
                preparedStmt.setString(3, PTCDCT);
                preparedStmt.setInt(4, OFNUP);
                preparedStmt.setString(5, TFCCMP);
                preparedStmt.setString(6, TFCPAI);
                preparedStmt.executeUpdate(querq);
               
                //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(querq);
 
          
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Algum valor não está correto!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage()); 
        }
```

I dont know what i did wrong.
Its my first post if you have any questions about what im asking please tell me.

Comment: can you translate the error message?

Comment: [documentation about SQL0418](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzala/rzalaml.htm) says what can be wrong. Probably the DB doesn't know which types are `?, convert(datetime, ?, 111)` at prepare time

Comment: error [SQL0418] Use of parameter marker or NULL not valid.

Comment: I will check the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run your code, does anything run on the AS400?

When I troubleshoot these sorts of things I like to start at the basics.  Here is an SQL procedure that sends a message to the QSYSOPR message queue:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE qgpl/testHello(                         
 )                                                                  
LANGUAGE    SQL                                                     
BEGIN                                                               
                                                                    
declare     vCmd char(512) default ' ' ;                            
declare     vCmdLgth decimal(15,5) default 0 ;                      
                                                                    
set         vCmd = 'SNDMSG MSG(''test hello'') TOUSR(*SYSOPR)' ;    
set         vCmdLgth = 80 ;                                         
call    qcmdexc( vCmd, vCmdLgth ) ;                                 
                                                                    
end
```

use the STRSQL command prompt to create the procedure and then run it. Then DSPMSG QSYSOPR to see the message in QSYSOPR message queue.

Next, change your java code to "call qgpl/testHello"  instead of the "insert into ..." code. When you run the java code you should see the message in QSYSOPR.

Comment: The thing is I have other buttons that do some insert in the database only this one is giving me the error

Comment: move your INSERT INTO statement into an SQL procedure. Replace the INSERT INTO statement in the java code with a call to the SQL procedure.  Then in the SQL procedure you can insert code that helps track down the joblog of the job running on the server. That will show you the SQL error caused by the INSERT INTO statement. You can even run code in the SQL procedure to DSPJOBLOG if one is not produced automatically.